# Selenium получение элемента из той же строки по xpath

Tags: python, python-2.x, xpath

Есть такая строка из таблицы:

```
<tr id='218A90E'>
  <td>foo</td>
  <td>bar</td>
  <td class="my_link">UserName</td>
  <td>
    <input  type='checkbox' title='Remove'> 
 </td>
</tr>
```

id каждый раз генерируется заново. Я знаю UserName и хочу кликнуть на checkbox напротив данного UserName. Этим я нахожу элемент с данным UserName:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='my_link' and text()='UserName']")
```

Вопрос: как добраться до элемента `checkbox` через `xpath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В XPath  есть так называемые ветви (оси) (это Вам надо почитать). 
Мне кажется для Вас будет справедливо следующее решение:

`//td[@class='my_link' and text()='UserName']/following-sibling::td[./input]/input`

Это первый вариант "ВЛОБ". Этот запрос находит ваш ТД с класом=му_линк и текстом=юсернэйм, дальше на уровне этого ТД находит элементы следующие за ним, в нашем случае это искомый ТД, который содержит инпут уровнем глубже, и спускается на уровень глубже. Если у Вас инпутов много разных то, добавьте условия типо `input[@type=checkbox]`.

- Минус этого варианта в его корявости.
- Плюс в том что он довольно гибкий, и быстро настраиваемый.

Можно воспользоваться вторым вариантом:

`//input[../preceding-sibling::td[@class="my_link" and text()='UserName'] and @type="checkbox"]`

- Минусом второго варианта является ступенька ../, но и ее можно обойти если понадобится
- Плюс более грамотный (красивый) подход.

Итоговый вариант:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("Первый или второй вариант")`

Comment: У меня заработало с 
`//td[@class='my_link' and text()='UserName']/preceding-sibling::td[./input]/input`, огромное спасибо! :)

Comment: @nick_gabpe вместо правки текущего ответа, дайте просто новый ответ с вашими улучшениями.

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='my_link' and text()='UserName']/input")
```

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@id="218A90E"]/td[4]/input")

Comment: вы можете воспользоваться кнопкой [edit], чтобы внести уточнения ;-)